# REGEX error when using with `list(FILTER)`

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` which compiles my C++ project. The "problem" is that I used to define the source files that should be compiled like:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp src/file1.cpp ... src/fileN.cpp)
add_executable(MY_PROJECT_NAME ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

All the *.cpp files are in the src directory. There are some cases where I don't want to compile some of these files, so I rewrote the snippet to:

```
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp)
list(FILTER SOURCE_FILES EXCLUDE REGEX "FILE_I_DO_NOT_WANT.cpp$" ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(MY_PROJECT_NAME ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

but I get the following error on CMake version 3.17.2:

```
list sub-command FILTER, mode REGEX requires five arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMake documentation for [`list(filter ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/list.html#filter) has the following syntax:

> ```
> list(FILTER <list> <INCLUDE|EXCLUDE> REGEX <regular_expression>)
> ```

There has never been a `MATCH` subcommand in this command (as there is with `string()`), nor is there a need to add the last argument `${SOURCE_FILES}`. So, your earlier version of CMake was likely interpreting `MATCH` as part of the regex, or silently ignoring it.

More recently, CMake has been making an effort to provide better error reporting to the user when commands are malformed. This is why you are now seeing the error in CMake version 3.17.

Comment: At first I tried to compile without `MATCH` after `regex`, but I was getting the exact same error, so I read the documentation about `string(regex ...)` and it needed `MATCH`/`MATCHALL`/`REPLACE`, that's why I wrote `MATCH`.

Comment: @TerensTare As explained in my response, you must *also* remove the last argument from the `list()` command (the trailing `${SOURCE_FILES}`). This is not part of the function signature. The last argument in the `list(FILTER ...)` command should be your regular expression. In CMake, the `list()` and `string()` commands accept **different** sets of subcommands.

Comment: The problem was that I was passing some regular expressions one after another, hence ( I suppose) I received those errors.